# ¿Cómo NO compilar un .JSP, en Eclipse con Maven?

Tags: java, jsp, apache, eclipse, maven

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto Java Web con Eclipse y Maven. 
Mi pregunta es, ¿se pueden ver los cambios realizados en un .jsp, en caliente? sin necesidad de volver a desplegar?
He probado a hacer refresh, Publish, clean, reiniciar servidores, etc. y no veo los cambios. 
Además cada vez que redespliego se me ven los cambios de la versión anterior, no la que acabo de guardar, así que tengo que redesplegar dos veces.

Soy muy nuevo en esto y creo que no lo estoy haciendo bien... una ayuda porfa?

Comment: ¿Tienes un tomcat instalado o lo lanzas con un comando maven como tomcat:run-war?

Comment: Copia por favor tu context.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los JSP's no los compila tu proyecto. Quien compila los JSP's de manera dinámica y crea los servlets (sí, un JSP termina convirtiéndose en un servlet) es el contenedor de servlets/servidor de aplicaciones. Si quieres cambiar el código JSP en caliente, es independiente al proyecto en el que estés trabajando. Conociendo esto, `Java`, `Maven`, `Eclipse` e incluso el mismo JSP están desasociados de la solución del problema.

No confundir un cambio en caliente con una característica del servidor que permite hacer un redespliegue automático al guardar los cambios en tu proyecto.

Dependiendo del servidor de aplicaciones que uses, puedes ubicar los JSPs dentro de las carpeta donde se ha desplegado la aplicación y modificarlos, de manera que el servidor de aplicaciones mismo lo actualice y lo modifique (si es que quieres cambiarlo **en caliente**). Asimismo, considera que tendrías que sincronizar manualmente los cambios hechos en los JSPs con los JSPs de tu proyecto.

Una alternativa que suelo usar para revisar este cambio es embeber el servidor en tu aplicación (en lo posible). Así, tendrías tu aplicación disponible para pruebas y debug a nivel personal y puedes modificar los JSPs directo en tu proyecto y ver los cambios en caliente. Un caso que puedo mostrar es el de embeber un Tomcat 8.

Agregar en maven:

```xml
<properties>
    <!-- otras propiedades que tengas en tu proyecto -->

    <!-- le agregamos una para tomcat 8 -->
    <tomcat.version>8.0.28</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--
        Dependencias de Tomcat embebido
        Para no agregarlo en el producto final
        recomiendo tener las dependencias en scope test
     -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Cambios en Java, dentro de un paquete en src/main/test:

```
public class TomcatRunner {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TomcatRunner.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
            Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
            //puerto a usar: 8080
            //lo puedes cambiar
            tomcat.setPort(8080);
            File webAppDir = new File(webappDirLocation);
            tomcat.addWebapp("/nombre-de-tu-app", webAppDir.getAbsolutePath());
            logger.info("configuring app with basedir: " + webAppDir.getAbsolutePath());

            tomcat.start();
            tomcat.getServer().await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception when initializing app", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Ejecutas (si quieres, en modo debug) la clase `TomcatRunner` y luego en tu browser podrás acceder a esta url: `http://localhost:8080/nombre-de-tu-app/`. Y esto soportaría los cambios de tus JSPs en caliente.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo en que la recarga de JSPs sea independiente del proyecto, ya que en base a su context.xml puede deshabilitarse.

Comment: Tomcat fue un ejemplo, puedes usar Jetty u otro. Además, puedes deshabilitarlo para producción, no viene bien hacerlo en tiempo de dev.

Comment: Acabo de ver que no pone nada de Tomcat en la pregunta, ¿debí leer mal la primera vez?

Comment: Y yo acabo de ver que no has leido toda mi respuesta: "Una alternativa que suelo usar para revisar este cambio es embeber el servidor en tu aplicación (...) Un caso que puedo mostrar es el de embeber un Tomcat 8". Es decir, Tomcat es **solo un ejemplo**. Puedes usar cualquier contenedor de servlets o servidor de aplicaciones que te ayude a lograr este fin.

Comment: Perdona si te he ofendido, pero no lo pretendía. Aludía a la pregunta original, mira el primer comentario a la respuesta o una respuesta mía a esta pregunta. Para nada me refería a tu respuesta ni era sarcasmo.

Comment: Si lo leí, pero mi respuesta con Tomcat no fue basada en ese comentario. Es más, yo uso Tomcat embebido en algunos proyectos web que tengo para hacer, el código que puse lo adapté de uno de los repositorios que uso. El hecho que yo haya usado tomcat es casualidad. También tengo un ejemplo de cómo embeber un Jetty 9 y cumplir el mismo propósito. Si es necesario actualizar la respuesta, lo haré.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción es que definas un configures el servidor de aplicaciones en el propio eclipse y luego "despliegues" tú aplicación en este servidor. Una forma rápida es con el botón derecho en tú proyecto y lances el menú de "Run As --> Run on server", de esta manera te permitirá configurar el servidor de aplicaciones.

Los cambios puedes ver los cambios en las JSP "en caliente" como dices.

Answer (score 0):

Una razón común por la que, en tomcat, no se produce una recarga en caliente de las JSPs es una mala configuración del contexto de la aplicación.

Esta configuración está definida en el fichero `META-INF/context.xml`.
Este fichero, al desplegarse la aplicación en el tomcat, será copiada a `/$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost`, y renombrado a `miAplicacion.xml`

Dentro del `context.xml` hay que comprobar si la propiedad `antiResourceLocking` está definida con el valor `true`, que impide la recarga de `JSP`s (ver [Bugzilla 37668](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37668)). Tanto la ausencia de esta propiedad como un `antiResourceLocking =false` implican que la recarga de `JSP`s sí estará habilitada.

En resumen:
`<Context path="/miAplicacion" antiResourceLocking="true">` implica que la recarga en caliente de JSPs no funcionará.